# update data in mysql database says successful but doesnt update

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert, sql-update

I'm having an issue updating my SQL database, it says successful but does not update the field in the database

```
// update data in mysql database 
$sql="UPDATE Triage SET Forename='$Forename', surname='$surname', DOB='$DOB' WHERE Reference='$Reference'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What does `mysql_error()` tell you? What's the return value from `mysql_query`? What will happen if a Mr O'Keefe signs up?

Comment: What says "Successful?"  Where?

Comment: Run your query in phpmyadmin and post the output here

Comment: `mysql_query` is deprecated. Invest in `mysqli_query`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php ....also use `mysql_affected_rows` to check how many rows were affected by your query too.

Comment: use like `mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: @Arran, agree - but look at the logic of your comment, you advise to use `mysqli_*` _and_ `mysql_affected_rows` :)

Comment: @davidkonrad, ha, well spotted :) (`mysqli_affected_rows` is where all the cool kids are hanging out OP, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php)

Comment: do you suggest that i change to mysqli then?, there should only ever be one row affected from my query

Answer (score 0):

Just try this code:

```
// update data in mysql database 
$sql="UPDATE Triage SET Forename='".$Forename."', surname='".$surname."', DOB='".$DOB."' WHERE Reference='".$Reference."'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);`
```

Comment: i have tried this but seems not to work, same issue.    
// Connect to server and select database.
 mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
 mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// update data in mysql database 
$sql="UPDATE Triage SET Forename='".$Forename."', surname='".$surname."', DOB='".$DOB."' WHERE Reference='".$Reference."'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
// if successfully updated. 
 if($result){
 echo "Successful";
 echo "<BR>";
 echo "<a href='list_records.php'>View result</a>";
 }
 else {
 echo "ERROR";
 }

Answer (score -1):

Try this after your query to identify the error:

```
if (!$sql) {
    die('Could not query:' . mysql_error());
}
```